# Unexpected end of JSON input whilr trying to post it to the sever

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Whenever I am trying to send a JSON object to server it gives me this particular error.

This is my Javascript code where I send the above JSON object to the action class but getting this error:

> error: [object Object] status: parsererror er:SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I need to understand what should be my JSON format? Is it OK or are changes required?

```js
function openLOV(obj) {     
    var requestData = {
        objId : "productLOV",
        attributes : [ {
            label : "URL_ID",
            column : "URL_ID",
            visible : "N"
        }, {
            label : "URL",
            column : "URL",
            visible : "Y"
        }],
        searchKey : "obj.value",
        queryKey : "SQL_GET_PRODUCT",
        callback : "cb"
    };

    var requestJSONData = JSON.stringify(requestData);
    alert(requestJSONData);

    var encrUrl = crcEncodeUrl("/EPSWeb/util/lovAction.do?mode=init&element="+obj.id);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : encrUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType : "application/json",
        data : requestJSONData,
        success : function(response) {
            $("#_lov_modal").remove();

            createLOVModal();

            $("#lovContent").html(response);
            $("#btnLOVModal").click();
        },
        error:function(data,status,er) {
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your JSON data is not valid, kindly check it.

Comment: please add a response

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth can u specify what should be my json data ?

Comment: This is the error in requestData Parse error on line 1:
{        objId : "productLOV"
---------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

Comment: The problem is with the response that the server is sending. It's supposed to be JSON, but it isn't.

Comment: Response from the server is not correct, as @Barmar said.

Comment: Yeah, can you put a debugger inside your success handler to inspect what you're getting as "response"?  My suspicion would be that you're getting some kind of 400 html; maybe you're missing a required header or something, so the request "succeeds", but it's sending you error html instead of your expected json.

Answer (score 0):

Its a data issue in the JSON you are sending to server,

in your variable requestData you need to add double quotes to the key fields, that makes the JSON valid. As mentioned below.

```
var requestData =  {
   "objId": "productLOV",
   "attributes": [{
      "label": "URL_ID",
      "column": "URL_ID",
      "visible": "N"
   },{
     "label": "URL",
     "column": "URL",
     "visible": "Y"
   }],
   "searchKey": "obj.value",
   "queryKey": "SQL_GET_PRODUCT",
   "callback": "cb"
 }
```

This would work.